# Why is this solution space to this recursion relation example and how did we get vector bases?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I am reading this text book about discrete math, and it says that space solution to this example: $ a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} ,a_0 = 2 ,a_1=5$

$ a_n = 2^n + 3^n$

$ x^2 = 5x -6$

and solution space is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/opFt6.jpg

I don't know how to get vector bases and would really like to understand how we got them.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by $5_{n-1}$?

Comment: @IshanDeo Sorry, I corrected a mistake